# AnyLogic - Importing database tables "null' error

Tags: r, excel, database, import, anylogic

I'm currently working on a simulation model in AnyLogic regarding the offloading process of wheat and maize at a big mill plant. I've filtered and altered the Excel workbooks given to me by the company, using RStudio, to extract the needed information regarding the model. Within RStudio I've exported the altered data sets as Excel workbooks with the idea in mind to import them in AnyLogic as database tables.
Now here is where the problem occurs. When using the "Import database tables..." window a "null" error window pops up when I try to import my Excel workbooks. 
I used the "xlsx" package in R with the following code:

```
write.xlsx(Truck_Wheat_Schedule, "RCL Truck Schedule Wheat.xlsx",sheetName = "Wheat_Schedule", col.names = TRUE, row.names = TRUE, append = FALSE)
write.xlsx(Truck_Maize_Schedule, "RCL Truck Schedule Maize.xlsx",sheetName = "Wheat_Schedule", col.names = TRUE, row.names = TRUE, append = FALSE)
```

Has this happened to anyone else and if so what is the resolution?

Comment: never happened to me. Make sure the Excel files are "clean", i.e. sheet names are free of special signs, actual sheet content looks like proper data tables (heading, each row has data...). Obviously, also try with manually created excel files: does the simplest possible file throw the same error? Maybe R is creating some hidden stuff in the xls file that throws things off.

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you share some of the code you use in R, namely what you're using to crease the Excel files from R: what package, and what functions/code.

Comment: @Benjamin I've successfully imported the unaltered Excel files, but they are very disorganized hence I took to R to ensure I have "clean" data.

Comment: well, then R is messing something up. Maybe copy and "paste as values" as a last step?

Comment: During the Create Database Table one of the options are to Paste the clipboard contents (3rd option), but then another error occurs. The error reads as follows:
Event Loop Exception
No enum constant com.anylogic.engine.TableTransferable.i.Error

Comment: That is not what I meant. Ensure your xls file is "clean", either by making sure R isn't adding some hidden stuff or using weird formats. And also by just copy and "paste as value" those tables into a new clean xls file manually. Isolate the problem, then seek help to solve it :-)